# saveframe() screenshots into file but cannot read image files in processing

Tags: processing

I want to use processing to take screenshots and use the screenshot to generate animations. The way I try to do it is save the frames into a directory and reload the image files into an image String. Not sure if it is the right way to do it, but I get error when I load the images:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q28u.jpg)

```
String[] listFileNames(String dir) {
  File file = new File(dir);
  if (file.isDirectory()) {
    String names[] = file.list();
    return names;
  } else {
    // If it's not a directory
    return null;
  }
}


void draw(){
  if (frameCount % 60 == 0) screen();
  if (screen != null) image(screen, 0, 0, width, height);
  if(recording){
    saveFrame("output//screenshot_####.png");
  }
  names = listFileNames("/Users/lj/Desktop/JingLang_vis145A_Midterm/screenshot/output/");
  print(names);
  if(names.length != 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i = i+1){
      img[i] = loadImage(names[i]);
      for (int j = 0; j < particles.length; j++) {
         particles[j].display();
         particles[j].move();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wonder if anyone knows the problem and if there is another way to do the screenshot animations.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that `listFileNames()` simply list the file names, not the absolute paths to the files. Unless those images are in the sketch directory (or within the data directory of the sketch) you will need to use the full path to the images to load them.

One option would be to concatenate the absolute directory path with the filename:

```
String[] listFileNames(String dir) {
  File file = new File(dir);
  if (file.isDirectory()) {
    String names[] = file.list();
    return names;
  } else {
    // If it's not a directory
    return null;
  }
}


void draw(){
  if (frameCount % 60 == 0) screen();
  if (screen != null) image(screen, 0, 0, width, height);
  if(recording){
    saveFrame("output//screenshot_####.png");
  }
  String dir = "/Users/lj/Desktop/JingLang_vis145A_Midterm/screenshot/output/"
  names = listFileNames(dir);
  print(names);
  if(names.length != 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i = i+1){
      // concatenate the directory with each fine name
      // dir inclues / at the end (otherwise you can use File.separator (e.g. dir/image.png = dir + File.separator + "image.png"))
      img[i] = loadImage(dir + names[i]);
      for (int j = 0; j < particles.length; j++) {
         particles[j].display();
         particles[j].move();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could use `listFiles()` instead which returns `File` objects that do provide the absolute path.

Here's a snippet illustrating usage of `listFiles()`:

```
File[] listFiles(String dir) {
  File file = new File(dir);
  if (file.isDirectory()) {
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    return files;
  } else {
    // If it's not a directory
    return null;
  }
}

File[] files;

void draw(){
  if (frameCount % 60 == 0) screen();
  if (screen != null) image(screen, 0, 0, width, height);
  if(recording){
    saveFrame("output//screenshot_####.png");
  }
  String dir = "/Users/lj/Desktop/JingLang_vis145A_Midterm/screenshot/output/"
  files = listFiles(dir);

  if(files == null) {
    println(dir + "is not a directory");
    return;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i = i+1){
    // concatenate the directory with each fine name
    // dir inclues / at the end (otherwise you can use File.separator (e.g. dir/image.png = dir + File.separator + "image.png"))
    img[i] = loadImage(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
    for (int j = 0; j < particles.length; j++) {
       particles[j].display();
       particles[j].move();
    }
  }
}
```

You can find this function and a few more under Daniel Shiffman's **DirectoryList** example via **Processing > Examples > Topics > File IO**

Additionally, [`listFiles()`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#listFiles-java.io.File-java.lang.String...-) / [`listPaths()`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#listPaths-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-)  are present in Processing already, just a bit tucked away. The nice thing about these variants is that you can filter results to be files with png extension only (e.g. excluding folder, hidden files, etc.).

Here's a modified version of the above snippet:

```
void draw(){
  if (frameCount % 60 == 0) screen();
  if (screen != null) image(screen, 0, 0, width, height);
  if(recording){
    saveFrame("output//screenshot_####.png");
  }
  String dir = "/Users/lj/Desktop/JingLang_vis145A_Midterm/screenshot/output/"
  File[] files = listFiles(dir,"files","extension=png")

  if(files == null) {
    println(dir + "is not a directory");
    return;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i = i+1){
    // concatenate the directory with each fine name
    // dir inclues / at the end (otherwise you can use File.separator (e.g. dir/image.png = dir + File.separator + "image.png"))
    img[i] = loadImage(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
    for (int j = 0; j < particles.length; j++) {
       particles[j].display();
       particles[j].move();
    }
  }
}
```

A bit off-topic from your question I am noticing a few confusing things:

1. you're listing files and loading images multiple times per frame in `draw()`. You might want to load the images once in `setup()`, store them in a `PImage[]`, then simply use them in `draw()`
2. It appears you're updating particles only while loading images and there doesn't seem to be a connection between the loaded images and the particles from the code you're shared. You might want to separate the particle code from the image loading code

Shameless plug: If you want to easily load and display png sequences in Processing you can use the [ImageSequencePlayer Processing library](https://github.com/hirschandmann/image-sequence-player) I worked on:

```
// import library
import com.hirschandmann.image.*;
// create a reference to an image sequence
ISPlayer player;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  // create instance and load all valid images from the data folder
  player = new ISPlayer(this,"/Users/lj/Desktop/JingLang_vis145A_Midterm/screenshot/output/"));
}

void draw() {
  // clear background with yellow
  background(255, 204, 0);
  // render image sequence, ISPlayer extends PImage, use it as such
  image(player,mouseX,mouseY);
}

// image sequence events
// all frames loaded
void onSequenceLoaded(ISPlayer player){
  println(player+" sequence fully loaded");
  player.loop();
}
```

[image: image sequence gif]